# WMS/WFS interface based on layer data stored in ObjectStorage (Swift)

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, mapserver

Currently I am using GeoServer to visualize raster and vector data stored in PostGIS using the WMS interface.

Now we are planning to move to a Cloud-Environment (Cloud Foundry) where no PostGIS extension and no file system are available, but only a ObjectStorage (Swift) where raster and vector data can be stored. I can access those files with an API and REST interfaces. So far as I know this data source is not supported by GeoServer or MapServer.

My question is if someone has an idea how I can use my raster and layer data stored in the ObjectStorage as a data source to provide a WMS interface for data visualization.

Is there any mapserver-software that supports ObjectStorage or any other way to access and visualize the geo data stored there?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a new [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) [DataStore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/datastore.html) which can then be added to [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org). If you have an existing API to work with then it should be a fairly easy task to do, especially if you only need read access. There is a [comprehensive tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/datastore/index.html) you can follow which we teach to people with only a morning's experience of GeoTools.

Once you have a new datastore you can just drop the jar into GeoServer and it will show up as a new store.

Comment: Thanks, I just read quickly over the tutorial and saw that it only talks about vector data. Do you know if I can use it for raster data (including pyramids/overlays) as well?

Comment: The principals are similar but more complex, feel free to ask on the dev list for help as you go along.